# Datecolumn: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type 'System.String'

Tags: c#, sql, datetime, extjs

I have a sql table with a column [WelcomeSent] with type: Datetime *and null values existing in this column*

I have this code to get the values from my DB and store them in a grid:

```
var result = (from i in dc.vw_Users where i.id == id select i).ToList(); //error line
storeUsers.DataSource = result;
storeUsers.DataBind();
```

In my grid there is a column:

```
<ext:DateColumn runat="server" ID="ColUsersWelcomeSent"     DataIndex="WelcomeSent"     Text="WelcomeSent"  Width="80"  Format="dd/MM/yyyy" Hidden="true"></ext:DateColumn>
```

But when I run it I receive this error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTime' to type
>   'System.String'

Anyone know how I can fix that?

Comment: did you check values in result by debugging before declare it as DataSource? Are they only date time values?

Comment: this is WelcomeSent contents from a row: 2017-03-09 00:00:00.000

Comment: var result = ((from i in dc.vw_Users where i.id == id select i).toString()).ToList();

can you try like this please and say if it gives same or another error.

Comment: @ReadyFreddy well I tried this , I didnt receive any error but now there are no contents in the grid only empty lines

Comment: Also why does your column have hidden="true" attiribute. Can you please delete it and try like that. Probably if you didn't get any errors, you passed data to column but this hidden makes it not visible i think.

Comment: No its hidden because I dont want to render it. Nothing to do with this. The problem is that the grid has other columns too but they are all empty. Only empty lines are there

Comment: So i think we need more code and info to solve this problem. For now my only advice can be that to try deleting toList(). and directly add toString(); here. I don't know much about linq but toList() may be create a new List for each loop and it may cause some weird problems. 

- Just try to:

// Change toList to toString(); 
//Delete toList and also dont add toString(); 
//Delete toList and use it after you took results like result = result.toList() or something like that. Thats all you can do by this code.

Comment: Same results. Empty rows. Let me know if you need another code snippet

Comment: Just for be sure that is there is a problem about result, can u try to get only first element by using var result = (from i in dc.vw_Users where i.id == id select i).FirstOrDefault(); and see if there will be any data at your grid. If there will be not any data again. We need more experienced people here

Comment: same error... But what I found by using breakpoints is that the problem is in this line: var result = (from i in dc.vw_Users where i.id == id select i).ToList(); It doesnt go to the next line (storeUsers2.DataSource = result;)

Comment: maybe this line is producing a string holder in result then it tries to cast datetime in it by another loop. This may occure if you send null or empty values to result from date column of your DB. Sorry but not experienced enough about linq to solve this. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by getting each column separately and parsing Date Column:

```
var result = from i in dc.vw_Users
    where i.id == id
    select new
    {
        i.UserId,
        i.id,
        i.SiId,
        i.FullName,
        i.UserName,
        i.RoId,
        i.Ro,
        i.Email,
        WelcomeSent =
            i.WelcomeSent != null && i.WelcomeSent.ToString().Length > 0
                ? DateTime.Parse(i.WelcomeSent.ToString())
                : new DateTime(),
        i.Signed,
        i.IsPri,
        i.IsApproved,
        IsLocked = i.IsLockedOut,
        i.LoginStatus,
        i.LastLoginDate,
        i.SignRights,
        i.LastPasswordChangedDate,
        i.FailedPasswordAttemptCount,
        i.CompleteDate,
        i.AccessDate,
        i.CertificationDate,
        i.CertificateId,
        i.progress
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert `toString()` your date value in `linq` result object before assigning it in `storeUsers.DataSource = result;`

Comment: Can you tell me how I can do that?I tried 

var result = (from i in dc.vw_Users where i.id == id select i).ToList().ToString();

With no luck... But my grid column is DateColumn. Shouldnt work as it is now?

Comment: you need to have some properties in result object. could you please post what result has for example date of birth?

Comment: this is WelcomeSent contents from a row: 2017-03-09 00:00:00.000

Comment: First your WelcomeSent property needs to be string.

Comment: Otherwise you need to catch in foreach loop for every item's WelcomeSent porperty in your results list and convert it to string.

Comment: Tried this: var result = (from i in dc.vw_Users where i.CTid == ctid select i).ToList().ForEach(u => u.WelcomeSent.ToString()); But I received:Cannot assign void to an implicitly-typed local variable

Comment: could you please add null check for this WelcomeSent prop

Comment: (from i in dc.vw_Users where i.CTid == ctid select i).ToList().ForEach(u => { if (u.WelcomeSent != null) { u.WelcomeSent.ToString(); } }); like this? same error...